# How to get order->price in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm trying to get 'order price' and other detail.

but the `$order->get_order_total` return nothing and no error appear.

How to get order meta and detail?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function($order_id){

  global $wpdb;
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

  if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
    $wpdb->show_errors = TRUE;
    $wpdb->suppress_errors = FALSE;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "Arvand_Marketing";
    $amount =  $order->get_order_total;
    $user_market = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'extra-field', true );
    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'email' => '$user_market', 'amount'=>'$amount') );

    if ($wpdb->last_error) {
      die('error=' . var_dump($wpdb->last_query) . ',' . var_dump($wpdb->error));
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`get_order_total()` isn't a thing. You'll need to use the [`get_formatted_order_total()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_formatted_order_total) method or the [`get_total()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_total) method.

```
// Get the formatted order total
$order->get_formatted_order_total();

// Get the stored order total (makes use of $order->order_total)
$order->get_total();
```

Comment: Links are dead.