# Woocommerce which hook to use for order status changes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-theming

In my custom plugin I need to catch every time an order status changes from `wc_on_hold` to `wc_completed` so I tried to write down:

```
function so_status_completed( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {       
    
    // if user is active , then get order amount and do all other personal calculations
    
    global $wpdb;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    //$payment_method = $order->get_payment_method(); //returns payment method bacs,cheque,cod etc
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $total = $order->get_total();
    $order_data = $order->get_data(); 
    //$order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    
    echo '<script>console.log("Debug Objects: Check order_total ' . $order_total. '");</script>';

}
add_action('woocommerce_order_payment_status_changed','so_status_completed',10,1);
```

But when I tried to change an order test from suspended to completed, I couldn't get on Chrome's Console that echo giving me the order price.....maybe using add_action isn't the right way to put a listener to that event?

Plus, since I am just here, I am using $order-get_total() which I searched on the net about his functionality but no deep docs found so I want to ask you if that method is the right one to retrieve order amount without fee applied?

Thanks! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *"I need to catch every time an order status changes from `wc_on_hold` to `wc_completed`"*

You would need to change your hook to `woocommerce_order_status_changed`.

> *"I couldn't get on Chrome's Console that echo giving me the order price"*

You can't use `javascript` and `console.log` in this hook. You would need to either use the `die` function or the `error_log` function to log it to your `debug.log` file.

---

#### 1- Using [`die`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) function

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);

function so_status_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status)
{

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    //$order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    $order_total = $order->get_total();

    die($order_total);
}
```

---

#### 2- Using [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);

function so_status_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status)
{

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    //$order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    $order_total = $order->get_total();

    error_log(print_r('order total: ' . $order_total, true));
}
```

**Note:**

- In order for this to work, you would need to activate "debugging" mode in your `wp-config.php` file. So, navigate to your `wp-config.php` file and add the following lines to it!
  (NOT RECOMMENDED IN THE PRODUCTION)

```php
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

---

#### 3- Creating a simple logger using [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function!

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);

function so_status_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status)
{

  $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

  //$order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
  $order_total = $order->get_total();

  // Simple logger 
  file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/my_logger.txt', $order_total);
}
```

- If "my_logger.txt" does not exist, it'll be created. If it already exists, then it'll be overwritten!

You could use `"append"` mode with your logger, if you need to! So your logger file won't get overwritten.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'so_status_completed', 10, 3);

function so_status_completed($order_id, $old_status, $new_status)
{

  $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

  //$order_total = $order->get_formatted_order_total();
  $order_total = $order->get_total();

  // Logger with "append" mode
  file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/my_logger.txt', $order_total, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

---

##### Second question

> *"since I am just here, I want to ask you if `$order-get_total()` is the right one to retrieve order amount without fee applied?"*

You might want to take a look at the `$order->get_subtotal()` for the totals before shipping, coupons and taxes:

Please see these related answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47782647/15040627
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61102779/15040627
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32634480/15040627
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708344/15040627