# Run function on WooCommerce checkout and check order status

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I have built a function that takes data from every WooCommerce order and saves in the database for me to withdraw statistic from. For example I am saving and adding all the total amount per category and then performs some calculations with this data. And this function works great, no issues. But the function also saves data from orders that are cancelled and refunded. I only want to process my code on orders that are completed and paid.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_data_to_stats' );
function save_data_to_stats( $order_id ) {
    
    $theorder = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $products = $theorder->get_items();

    ...
}
```

I get that a refunded order will be processed as it will be completed first and then refunded. For this I have to find a way to run a function when it the order changes status to refunded and then build a new function to handle this. But how do I run a function when the order changed to refunded?

For the cancelled orders. Can I find another hook that fires only on when the order is completed/paied. Maybe the **woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta** is not the right one?

Comment: Can you provide in your question the **complete** function code please…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce which hook to use for order status changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005441/woocommerce-which-hook-to-use-for-order-status-changes)